# Excel Rodent Simulation

Tags: excel, if-statement, statistics, probability

The population of a rodent colony starts at 50 and each rodent has a probability of 1/6 that it will die of disease each day. This can be simulated by a spreadsheet which contains 50 “dice” and on each “roll”, if the die comes out a 6, it is removed. Perform this simulation and compare it to the theoretical decline of the rodent colony.

Currently I have gotten to the point were I have done the simulation and if the rodent lands on the number 6 it dies (cell goes blank). Current formula:

```
 =IF(B2=6,"",RANDBETWEEN(1,6))
```

I just need to figure out if the rodent dies on, lets say day 12 all that will happen is a blank space on day 13 and it will just restart the simulation on day 15.

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvpZZ.png)

As you can see, the first rodent died on day 1 (r.i.p) so day 2 there is a blank space but on day 3 there is a random number generated (1/6). I want to know if the mouse died how can we make the rest of the cells black in the rodent column.

Comment: have you looked at conditional formatting? ie if 6 then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF()

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A2:A2,6),"",RANDBETWEEN(1,6))
```

Put that in B2 copy over and down.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Don't just check for the previous cell to be 6, but also to be `""`:

```
=IF(OR(B2="",B2=6),"",RANDBETWEEN(1,6))
```

And populate as needed

Comment: or: `=IF(OR(A2={"",6}),"",RANDBETWEEN(1,6))`